# The pop up box used for user annotations does not close when the action is completed

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface, moderator-tools, annotations

Can we please have a more intuitive user experience when annotating user accounts?

The pop up box when annotating user accounts does not close when submitted. It's counter intuitive to the process of task completion. The clarification at the top is not helpful. Usually the moderator workflow would be the moderator moving to a new, unrelated task.

### Preparing the annotation

> [image]

### After submitting the annotation

> [image]

It also creates a second annotation if I hit submit twice.. I suspect this could continue for a while.. but time.

### Prepared annotation

> [image]

### First submission

> [image]

### Second submission

> [image]

### Resulting Annotations

[image]

***Caveat:** This rude mod message was sent to my sock account that is used brutally for testing.*

Comment: Intermediately desired solution could be to clear the annotation field after submitting.

Comment: @Luuklag yep but it actually took some getting used to, to realise the annotation had been posted. Not a good UI me thinks. I can live with it, but can see others falling for that pop up non disappearing trick... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed.

There were three moderator actions on that form which do not require a navigation change to complete their work: annotate, clear sessions, and unsuspend.  For whatever reason, I was just leaving the menu up.  Now, annotate and clear sessions will hide the menu and display their success messages, while unsuspend will refresh the page, since it affects the page in a more dramatic way.